# Run Flutter in both iOS and Web at the same time

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I am trying to build and run a project in both iOS and Web from VS Code. Is there any way to do this?

I have tried running `flutter run -d all` but that only runs iOS, even though `flutter devices` lists both of them

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you can create a *compound* launch config in your `.vscode/launch.json`. This one creates three configs, one to launch on the current device (shown in the status bar), one to launch on iOS, and one to launch on Android. It then creates a compound config that will launch on iOS and Android devices at the same time. You can change one of the device IDs to `chrome` to launch on Chrome.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Current Device",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart"
        },
        {
            "name": "Android",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "deviceId": "android"
        },
        {
            "name": "iPhone",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "deviceId": "iphone"
        },
    ],
    "compounds": [
        {
            "name": "All Devices",
            "configurations": ["Android", "iPhone"],
        }
    ]
}
```

More info can be found [on the Flutter wiki](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Multi-device-debugging-in-VS-Code).